# Facebook Share Button on mobile view

Tags: facebook, button, mobile, share

Conquistadores!

I implemented an facebook share button, that works absolutely fine **except** in mobile view. Have a look: http://parkfreunde-weissensee.berlin/2017/07/04/jetzt-handeln-die-gelegenheit-war-nie-so-guenstig

Looks like the URL will not be transfered on smartphones. Any idea where I have to trim the code?

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=123456789";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And the Button

```html
  <div class="facebook-share__article-footer__container">
   <div class="facebook-share__article-footer">
    <?php
     // $title=urlencode('');
     $url=urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID));
     // $summary=urlencode('');
     // $image=urlencode('');
    ?>
   <a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" target="_parent" href="javascript: void(0)" class="single-post__social-media-button-invert">Auf Facebook teilen</a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Best regards from Berlin
Tibor

Comment: FYI: Passing additional parameters such as title, description, thumbnail dynamically at the time of sharing is in the process of being removed, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Comment: O.k., thanks CBroe. Could you help me with a valid, simple code-snippet for my unsophisticated standard purpose: sharing title, excerpt, image and url (as it works on the desktop-view).

Comment: Passing those additional parameters is going to stop working in your desktop view soon as well. You can _only_ specify the URL to be shared, all other data will be taken from the OG meta data that URL returns.